# Remove From string in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string:-

```
<p>my string data <br />
<p>We understand the challenges</p> <strong> that small to medium</strong> my string data my string data my string data </p>
```

I want remove only first using php plz help

Target as:-

```
my string data <br />
    <p>We understand the challenges</p> <strong> that small to medium</strong> my string data my string data my string data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Do you want to remove first tag or first <p> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you want to remove the first p tag from the string, You can use php trim

```
$string = '<p>my string data <br />
           <p>We understand the challenges</p> <strong> that small to medium</strong> my string data my string data my string data </p>';

$result_string = rtrim(ltrim(trim($string), '<p>'), '</p>');
echo $result_string;
```